Playwright e2e waitForEvent exceeds timeout value
I'm using playwright for e2e and I have such code to fill in email/pwd and get redirected after successful login:
const {expect, test} = require('@playwright/test');
const {
  signUrl,
  testUser,
  homeUrl,
} = require('../data/const');

test.describe('E2E Social', () => {
  test.beforeEach(async ({page}, testInfo) => {
    console.log(`Running ${testInfo.title}`);
  });

  test.describe('sign in page', () => {
    test('can sign in', async ({ page, context }) => {
      await page.goto(signUrl);

      await page.locator('input[type="email"]').first().fill(testUser.login);
      await page
        .locator('input[type="password"]')
        .first()
        .fill(testUser.pwd);

      const submitButton = page.locator('input[type="submit"]');
      await expect(submitButton).toBeVisible();
      await expect(submitButton).toHaveText('Log in');

      const [loginPage] = await Promise.all([
        context.waitForEvent('page'),
        submitButton.click(),
      ]);
      await loginPage.waitForLoadState();
      await loginPage.bringToFront();
      await loginPage.waitForTimeout(5000);

      await expect(loginPage.url()).toBe(homeUrl);
    });
  });
});


but for whatever reasons I see that it goes to the new page (screenshots), but... after 30sec test is canceled with
waitForEvent('page') Test timeout of 30000ms exceeded.

What I do wrong?

Can you share a [mcve] of the page you're automating? I'd avoid timeouts and if it's a redirect probably use waitForURL().

@ggorlen it's the same...

What do you mean by "it's the same"? The post has no changes--please share that [mcve]. Thanks.

Try to rewrite it to Events syntax instead of Promise.all
const pagePromise = context.waitForEvent("page", { timeout: 10_000 });
await submitButton.click();
const loginPage = await pagePromise;

If new page is really there of course
As an alternative wait for a new page - just to check that page is there
// add a timeout if needed
expect(context.pages()).toHaveLength(2)


still no... Error: browserContext.waitForEvent: Timeout 10000ms exceeded while waiting for event "page"
but in timeline I see that it's on a new page...

This code is functionally identical to the Promise.all version.

@ggorlen in this case yes. But sometimes it's not https://github.com/microsoft/playwright/issues/5470#issuecomment-1285640689

@byCoder if you're saying that you see a new tab and page event is not triggered - try to wait some time and wait for context.pages().lenght === 2

Never use sleeps or waits. lenght is a typo. Basically, this answer doesn't solve OP's problem and offers bad advice. OP needs to provide a [mcve] before this question can be answered.
